# Reorder names with java regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a series of names that take the form:

1. Smith, John Walter
2. Jones, James Samuel, Jr.

I'm struggling to find a regex which will allow me to extract each element as an individual text element.  My code currently looks as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?), (.+?) (.*)(?:, )((.*))?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( name2 );

System.out.println( matcher.find() );     
System.out.println( matcher.groupCount() );
System.out.println( matcher.group( 1 ) );  
System.out.println( matcher.group( 2 ) );  
System.out.println( matcher.group( 3 ) );  
System.out.println( matcher.group( 4 ) )
```

This pattern matches the second name format, allowing me to extract its component parts but does not match the first (no doubt due to the look ahead).  When I make the look ahead optional (`(.+?), (.+?) (.*)(?:, )?((.*))?$`), I match the first name format, but I capture both the middle name and suffix when I use the second name format.  I'm sure there is an easy way to accomplish what I am after, but I am relatively inexperienced when it comes to regex.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How about using `String.split()` method: `name2.split(",")`

Comment: What are the elements you want to extract from the examples given? Moreover, what is the final result (after "reordering") you want?

Comment: This kind of question has been asked many times. If you don't have a fixed format - trying to parse it is useless, and if you have a specific format - remove all the commas/dots/etc and extract the first/last-names with a simple split() (over whitespaces). Trying to find a silver-bullet regex is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no lookahead in your pattern.  Patterns with `(?:pattern)` are called *non-capturing groups*.  They're just like regular matches, except that they allow you to group stuff in parentheses without having a `group(n)` number assigned to them.  This is fine because you really don't need a lookahead for this purpose.

What you need is to say that the comma and the suffix, *taken as a group*, are optional.  To do this, put the comma and the suffix in parentheses (you can use `(?:` here), and put a `?` after the whole group:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?), (.+?) (.*)(?:, (.*))?$");
```

However, this won't solve your second problem, which is that the third group `(.*)` will consume as many characters as it can.  Since the last part (comma + suffix) is optional, the regex finds that it can consume the rest of the string and still get a match.  To fix this, you can either make it a reluctant match, like you did for the first two groups:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?), (.+?) (.*?)(?:, (.*))?$");
```

or just tell the `(.*)` not to match any commas:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?), (.+?) ([^,]*)(?:, (.*))?$");
```

**Note:** I haven't tested either of these yet.